# Restrict selected checkboxes to number of 5

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have six checkboxes, by default two checkboxes will be selected at loading time, and after I want to select more checkboxes , but if I try to select all checkboxes It will show alert and not possible to select all. Means in every condition it can select one or upto five checkboxes. So How Can I implement this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Checkboxgroup and validate on change. Here's a working example:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
    fieldLabel: 'Two Columns',
    // Arrange checkboxes into two columns, distributed vertically
    columns: 2,
    vertical: true,
    msgTarget: 'title',
    listeners: {
        change: function(cb,nv,ov) {
            if(Ext.isArray(nv.rb)) {
                if(nv.rb.length > 5){
                    cb.markInvalid('You can select only 5!');
                } else {
                   cb.clearInvalid(); 
                }
            } else {
                cb.markInvalid('You need to select at least 2!');
            }
        }
    },
    items: [
        { boxLabel: 'Item 1', name: 'rb', inputValue: '1', checked: true },
        { boxLabel: 'Item 2', name: 'rb', inputValue: '2', checked: true },
        { boxLabel: 'Item 3', name: 'rb', inputValue: '3' },
        { boxLabel: 'Item 4', name: 'rb', inputValue: '4' },
        { boxLabel: 'Item 5', name: 'rb', inputValue: '5' },
        { boxLabel: 'Item 6', name: 'rb', inputValue: '6' }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But I have these checkboxes in different containers

Comment: @KiranPardeshi Than you need a central place where you register the events for all of your combos and increment/decrement a internal counter. Basically the same except you have to register all your combos by yourself. If all combos under the same container you may also consider to bubble the change event up.